# Main service stopping himself after running function that stops another service

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a C# service called Dlocker, Dlocker has another service called DlockerUpdate, that updates Dlocker.
I'm making a function to Dlocker called `checkUpdaterUpdates()` that will check if a file called DlockerUpdate.exe.new exists in the DlockerUpdate folder, if exists, it will follow these steps:

- Stop the service domtoolsupdate (DlockerUpdate.exe)
- Remove the old DlockerUpdate.exe file
- Rename DlockerUpdate.exe.new to DlockerUpdate.exe
- Start the service

Here is the code for the `StopService()`, `StartService()` and `checkUpdaterUpdates()`:

```
private void StartService()
        {
            try
            {
                helper.WriteToFile("{0} inside startService");
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/C net start domtoolsupdate";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                helper.WriteToFile("{0} error: " + error);
            }
            helper.WriteToFile("{0} DlockerUpdate Started");
        }
```

```
private void StopService()
        {
            try
            {
                helper.WriteToFile("{0} inside stopService");
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/C net stop domtoolsupdate";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                helper.WriteToFile("{0} error: " + error);
            }
            helper.WriteToFile("{0} DlockerUpdate Stopped");
        }
```

```
private void checkUpdaterUpdates()
        {
            var DlockerUpdatePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\update\\";
            if (File.Exists(DlockerUpdatePath + "DlockerUpdate.exe.new")) {
                helper.WriteToFile("in the if");
                StopService();
                File.Delete(DlockerUpdatePath + "DlockerUpdate.exe");
                helper.WriteToFile("deleted dlockerupdate.exe");
                File.Move(DlockerUpdatePath + "DlockerUpdate.exe.new", DlockerUpdatePath + "DlockerUpdate.exe");
                helper.WriteToFile("updated dlockerupdate.exe");
                StartService();
                helper.WriteToFile("started the service");
            }
        }
```

In the `StopService()`, instead of stopping only domtoolsupdate (DlockerUpdate.exe), it's stopping domtools (Dlocker.exe) and domtoolsupdate, and I can't find out why.

I've copied and adapted the start and stop service functions from DlockerUpdate.exe to work on Dlocker.exe, but it doesn't works for some reason.

As you have seen, in the code there is a function called `helper`, the helper is my debugger, when I call him, it writes on a file called Dlocker.log, when the stop service is running, this is the result of the helper:

[image: Dlocker.log]
The log does not return any signals of Dlocker.exe has stopped, but in the log of DlockerUpdate.exe, it returns that the service has been stopped:
[image: DLockerUpdate.log]
There's no function in DlockerUpdate.exe that kills Dlocker.exe when it's stopped.
What should I try?

Comment: Sounds like your service has a Dependency defined.

Comment: You can use the command line `sc enumdepend MyServiceName` , for each of your services to check if each of your services has a dependency.

Comment: I tried and they reutrn ``[SC] EnumDependentServices: entriesread = 0``

Comment: Have you tried using the [ServiceController](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/how-to-start-or-stop-a-windows-service-using-C-Sharp/) instead or launching a Process to call cmd?

Comment: Also as there is no DLocker Stopped message, I now suspect that DLocker is actually crashing, have a look in EventLogs for some crash reports

Comment: Add a try catch and your helper logging to the `checkUpdaterUpdates` method, it should be noted that calling net stop may not stop a service immeditaly, and so your File.Delete and File.Move  may be triggering exceptions as the file may still be in use.

Comment: Already tried to use ServiceController, will do the try catch and see if I get smth

Comment: Yo, I've tested here and the service is not authorized to delete the DlockerUpdate.exe file, the try catch worked, thanks!